# How to bundle a HTML app for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, webkit

I am writing a html5 stand alone app (not hosted on a server).  How do I package and deploy it to the iPhone simulator or (eventually) to the apple store?  Do I need to create a project in xcode that loads and display the app in a web view?  Are there any tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonegap is a very good tool to bundle your webapp into a phone app. It should able to help you ports to most of the popular platform :)

http://www.phonegap.com/

Comment: I was looking at that.  What is unclear to me is how much control I would have (plus I like to know how things work).  I don't want to click a button, then 'magic happens'.  If I choose to move away from phonegap, could I do so easily?  There are a few limitations to phonegap, so I would like to explore a native approach before I explore another option.

Comment: After more research I decided to give 'Appcelerator Titanium Mobile' a try.  Quynh, since my choice is more of a preference than a rejection of your reply, I'm voting up your answer.  Thanx.